# Issubclass and multiple inheritance

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, subclassing

I would like to figure out why a concrete child class is not considered a subclass of an abstract child class, when dealing with a multiple inheritance in Python.

See the code snippet below.

```
from abc import ABC


class AbstractFirstParent(ABC):
    pass


class AbstractSecondParent(ABC):
    pass


class AbstractChild(AbstractFirstParent, AbstractSecondParent):
    pass


class ConcreteFirstParent(AbstractFirstParent):
    pass


class ConcreteSecondParent(AbstractSecondParent):
    pass


class ConcreteChild(ConcreteFirstParent, ConcreteSecondParent):
    pass


print(issubclass(ConcreteChild, AbstractChild))
```

The output is `False`, however I expect that if `ConcreteChild` inherits from both `ConcreteFirstParent` and `ConcreteSecondParent`, then it inherits from `AbstractFirstParent` and `AbstractSecondParent`.
Consequently, it must inherit from `AbstractChild`, but for some reason it does not.

For example,

```
print(
    issubclass(ConcreteChild, AbstractFirstParent)
    and issubclass(ConcreteChild, AbstractSecondParent)
)
```

Gives `True`, which is expected.

Can anyone explain why `ConcreteChild` is not considered as a subclass of `AbstractChild`?

Thank you in advance!

Here is a visual representation of the hierarchy.

```
 AFP       ASP
 | \      / |
 |  \    /  |
 |   \  /   |
 |    AC    |
 CFP       CSP
  \        /
   \      /
    \    /
     \  /
      CC
```

The reason I am asking concerns the implementation of type checking for the system, where the various mixin classes are used to compose a concrete class.

From my point of view if `ConcreteChild` inherits from both abstract parents, just like `AbstractChild`, then it should inherit from the latter one.

Now I see that there is no direct connection between CC and AC, and this is the reason why `ConcreteChild` is not considered as a subclass of `AbstractChild`.
But it is not clear how one can deal with the type checking in this case.
Let us say, a function returns a `ConcreteChild` instance, while there may be various kinds of `ConcreteChild` based on various concrete parents.
All of the parents are based on `AbstractFirstParent` and `AbstractSecondParent`.
I wish that the type of the returned value from the function is `AbstractChild`, since it inherits from both abstract parents.

Can we tamper with `__subclasscheck__` in a way to make this work?

**Answer**

This approach, using a virtual inheritance helps.

```
class ChildMeta(type):
    def __subclasscheck__(cls, sub):
        return (
            issubclass(sub, AbstractFirstParent)
            and issubclass(sub, AbstractSecondParent)
        )


class AbstractChild(metaclass=ChildMeta):
    pass
```

In this case it works as expected.

```
print(issubclass(ConcreteChild, AbstractChild))
print(issubclass(ConcreteFirstParent, ConcreteChild))
```

Gives, as desired.

```
True
False
```

Comment: `AbstractChild` is its own class, not an intersection type or "both AbstractFirstParent and AbstractSecondParent". Being a subclass of AbstractFirstParent and AbstractSecondParent *doesn't* make a class a subclass of AbstractChild.

Answer (score 0):

`ConcreteFirstParent`, `ConcreteSecondParent` and `AbstractChild` are like siblings in the present code. `ConcreteChild` inherits from `ConcreteFirstParent` and `ConcreteSecondParent`, i.e. it does not inherit anything from `AbstractChild`. So `ConcreteChild` is indeed not a subclass of `AbstractChild`.

(Not entirely precise) sketch of the family-tree:

```
   AFP   ASP
   /   |   \
CFP   CSP   AC
    |
   CC
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I updated the question and the inheritance diagram. I presume, that the one you wrote does not reflect the actual hierarchy.